# Launching many copies of POSIX C++ code on GPU

Tags: linux, cuda, gpu, opencl, hpc

I have a very compute intensive single-threaded POSIX+boost C++ program that I just launch in many copies on a 48-core CPU (it's kind-a brute-force A* search algorithm)

Is there any easy way of recompiling the code for GPU and running on "many more" GPU cores?

What is the easiest way to port existing boost C++ code for GPU assuming I want to run the threads as-is?

Comment: In a word, no. There is no such thing as a free lunch...

Comment: @talonmies No is also an answer, and there does not seem to be a clear answer anywhere to whether it is possible or not. Thanks!

Comment: There is no method that I am aware of that simply involves recompilation of any arbitrary single-threaded code, to make it ready for GPU execution.  If you take advantage of [certain emerging C++17 features](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/supercomputing/2019/pdf/sc1936-gpu-programming-with-standard-c++17.pdf) it may be possible to write "standard" code that uses the GPU with just a recompilation.  Probably anything else will require some level of porting (i.e. refactoring of the code) and learning on your part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any easy way of recompiling the code for GPU and running on "many more" GPU cores?

No

> What is the easiest way to port existing boost C++ code for GPU assuming I want to run the threads as-is?

There isn't one. As noted in comments, C++17 includes [parallel algorithms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-c17-parallel-algorithms-for-better-performance/#:%7E:text=C%2B%2B17%20added%20support,tag%20was%20removed%20in%2015.7.), and NVIDIA ship a [C++17 compiler with CUDA support](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/accelerating-standard-c-with-gpus-using-stdpar/). That is a long way from taking a "POSIX C++" code and just running it directly on a GPU. No GPU programming paradigm I am familiar with works like that.

Answer (score 2):

To whoever is interested in why this is not possible (and probably will not be possible ever) is that GPU has a very specific compute logic that in general case would yield much lower performance than a single-threaded CPU, even if program is somehow launched on multiple cores:

- In a multi-core CPU, cores are separated as much as possible so that developer does not think about chip internals. Only a few things influence thread performance scaling: like memory bandwidth and (in some cases) simultaneous multi-threading effects.
- In a GPU, cores are "on purpose" tightly connected: for example, if a branching occurs differently in different threads, then a full group of cores (up to a hundred in some cases) would end up executing code sequentially, dropping all parallelization benefits. Additionally as the cores are in general "slower" their main benefit is in "vectorized" operations, requiring the developer to "think in vectors" and not in "data structures" to get nominal performance.

So while there are programming toolkits that "look like C" they are in fact domain-specific languages hidden behind C syntax and C-like library calls.

Making a "usable" translation from ordinary code to highly-parallel GPU code would require an algorithm that can load code as logic, find and prove correctness of equivalent logic transformations on scales of billions of grounded states, and translate it back to GPU instructions based on computational model of GPU. While potentially possible in the future, this is way beyond modern algorithmic knowledge and compute capacity. The sciences studying such endeavors include AI planning, Program synthesis, Automatic theorem proving, Deep Learning.